# How many times a week should I deadlift and squat as a beginner?

Tags: muscle, strength-training, exercise-technique, starting-strength, posture

I am a 32 year old guy. I haven't done deadlifts or squats before, but occasionally did workouts on individual muscle groups, and running.

I am looking forward to building strength, gaining muscle and eventually losing weight.

I would like to get started with deadlifts and squats to strengthen my core. Could anyone suggest a good way to get started?

Comment: Are you looking at a particular program?

Comment: I'd recommend following Starting Strength or Strong Lifts, by the numbers. You should be following the programs to a "t".

Comment: As a beginner, I highly recommend Strong Lifts for you. You'll need to purchase a barbell, bench for benchpress, and a squat rack. Or use a gym that has one. It'll be sooo worth it.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried out [5x5 training](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/) myself but it

> consists of two full body-workouts:
>
> ```
> Workout A: Squat, Bench Press, Barbell Row
> Workout B: Squat, Overhead Press, Deadlift,
> ```
>
> You train three times a week, alternating workout A and B, and resting
>   at least one day between two workouts. You never train two days in a
>   row because your body needs days off to get stronger.

So the frequency of workouts is set, you only adjust/increase the intensity/weight.

Comment: That's only one example of 5x5 training; many other schedules exist.

Comment: True. With several decades of history it would be quite sensational if everyone did it exactly the same way.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your answer to take that into account?

Comment: Really good program to start on!! however I would recommend to not do the OHP until you develop the right mobility, until you do you could probably do Overhead Dumbbell Presses instead.

Comment: thank you for the replies. could you tell me what a 5 x 5 training is.. is it  5 sets of 5 reps each?

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend the SS program ( Starting Strength) as a beginner.

http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs

In this program you will do squats 2 x a week.  and deadlifts 1 x a week.

Do this untill your lifts begin to stall (around 6 months), then swtich to an intermediate workout program.

Comment: That's not correct. SS squats 3x/week and many versions deadlift once or twice a week.

Comment: IT's funny how you state that the version in the answer is "wrong" and then states how menny times you do compound lift X in "your" version. Then say there are diferen versions of SS in the same sentance.

Comment: There is no version of SS that I know of that squats 2x/week. Squatting every session and having three sessions a week is the core of the program. You're right, some versions deadlift once a week, which is why I phrased it the way I did.

Comment: I literally have no idea what point you're trying to make. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Following programs could possibly be a good idea because it keeps you consistent and on schedule, but I personally don't do any of this.

I would suggest you deadlift and squat as many times as possible given that you rest appropriately. Typically, give 24-48 hours of rest in between each workout. An example plan (again, set appropriately according to your rest levels and schedule) would be `repeat: {deadlift | rest | squat | rest | rest}`.

This is assuming you are aiming for high-weight, low reps (aka strength/volume building) sets.

Comment: thanks for the replies.. what is the ideal rest time between sets ?